# Strava API returning "malformed request" on webhook registration

Tags: php, laravel, api, webhooks, strava

I'm trying to use Strava events, so i have to register a webhook. All fine.

**1)** I make a post request to initiate the process of registering the webhook.

```
    curl -X POST https://api.strava.com/api/v3/push_subscriptions \
    -F client_id=MY_APP_ID \
    -F client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET \
    -F 'callback_url=MY_DOMAIN/webhook/strava' \
    -F 'verify_token=MY_VERIFY_TOKEN'
```

**2)** I have my route setup

```
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/webhook/strava', 'StravaController@webhook');
```

**3)** My controller returns **valid json response** with code 200 **and all the data needed**

```
    public function webhook(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info($request->input('hub.challenge'));

        return response()->json([
            'hub.challenge' => $request->input('hub.challenge')
        ], 200);
    }
```

**But when i make the post it returns:**

```
{"message":"Bad Request","errors":[{"resource":"PushSubscription","field":"challenge response","code":"challenge response malformed"}]}
```

**Details**:
I noticed that the log statement is not fired. So maybe it's saying malformed becouse it's returning `{"hub.challenge": null}`. But i think in that case, the error message would be different.

Thank you guys!

Comment: If you're saying that code in your server isn't being called then the problem is with your initial post, isn't it? Are you sure `-F` is the option you want to be using with curl? That's typically for attaching files to a multipart form request, not a standard POST.

Comment: Just copied the curl from Strava, only changed the vars from the ones in my app: https://developers.strava.com/docs/webhooks/
So, how would you debug the response from my post to see if it is hitting the right route?

Comment: Check your web server logs would be step 1 I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, of course i did it. Log is empty.
I also tried other curl syntax but returning: `201{"message":"Bad Request","errors":[{"resource":"PushSubscription","field":"challenge response","code":"challenge response malformed"}]}
`

Comment: Ok so if nothing is getting back to your server, then you can remove items 2 and 3 from your question. It sounds like this is strictly a question of "what's wrong with my curl request." Have you contacted the API maintainers? Do they offer some kind of support or forum?

Answer (score 0):

use underscore. like this

```
$mode = $request->get('hub_mode');
$token = $request->get('hub_verify_token');
$challenge = $request->get('hub_challenge');
```

Answer (score -1):

Following Code response worked for me:

```
return response()->json([
    'hub.challenge' => Input::get('hub.challenge',Input::get("hub_challenge",TRUE))
], 200);
```